# Exception occurred processing WSGI script

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to install an open-source Django application ([**OSQA**](http://www.osqa.net/)) but i get this error:

```
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error] mod_wsgi (pid=82486): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa.wsgi'.
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error]   File "/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 232, in __call__
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error]     self.load_middleware()
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error]   File "/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 42, in load_middleware
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Tue Sep 24 10:37:09 2013] [error] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.sessions.middleware: "No module named base"
```

This is my `osqa.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa')

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'osqa.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

In *httpd.conf* i have `WSGIScriptAlias`:

```
WSGISocketPrefix ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
WSGIPythonPath /home/fuiba/webapps/osqa:/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/lib/python2.7  
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa.wsgi
```

In apache2 folder (`/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/apache2`) i get a file with strange name:  **${APACHE_RUN_DIR}.47892.0.1.sock**

What is it?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try to reconfigure the WSGI lik this for example by defining a general path for the project and apache

osqa.wsgi :

```
import os, sys

#path to directory of the .wgsi file ('[directory]/')
wsgi_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# path to project root directory (osqa '/')
project_dir = os.path.dirname(wsgi_dir)

# add project  directory to system's Path
sys.path.append(project_dir)
sys.path.append('/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa')


os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa/.python-egg'
#add the setting.py file to your system's path
project_settings = os.path.join(project_dir,'settings')

#explicitly define the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='osqa.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application =django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

in the http.conf :

keep only the WSGIScriptAlias in the virtualhost, the path going to be already define in the wsgi file

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/fuiba/webapps/osqa/osqa.wsgi
WSGIScriptReloading On
WSGIProcessGroup domain.com
WSGIDaemonProcess domain.com user=user processes=10 threads=1 maximum-requests=500
```

it should work if libapache2_mod_wsgi is installed too